# Jackon ObjectMapper Converts into LinkedHashMap instead of required class

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a Class (FirstClass) for deserialization :

```
 FirstClass {

String getStr();
void setSrt (String str);

List<SecondClass> getParams();
void setParams(List<SecondClass> params);

}

SecondClass {

String getStrTwo();
void setStrTwo(String strTwo);
}
```

For deserialization response into ArrayList I am using next thing:

```
  CollectionType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, FirstClass.class);

  List<T> result = mapper.readValue(response.getSpringResponse().getBody(), type);
```

Getting allmost correct ArrayList result,
but during invocation of
 `result.getParams()`  I am getting LinkedHashMap data with

> [ "srtTwo" , "valueFromResponse"]

data instead of `ArrayList<SecondClass> params`.

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Annotation @JsonDeserialize(
                as = ArrayList.class,
                contentAs = SecondClass.class) worked for me.

```
 FirstClass {

String getStr();
void setSrt (String str);

@JsonDeserialize(
            as = ArrayList.class,
            contentAs = SecondClass.class
    )
List<SecondClass> getParams();
void setParams(List<SecondClass> params);

}
```